# Keep all files when merging remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

So here's my situation:

Party A has a big huge project that needs a new_feature. Party B clones the repo and starts working on new_feature. However, Party B, lacking the requisite amount of caffeine and brain cells, and being new to Git, deleted all the files in his repo not related to new_feature to ease the burden of compiling and simplify the workspace. Now that new_feature is ready to merge back into Party A's repo, how does Party A merge it without the merge deleting any of his files?

(Note that Party A has little more Git experience than Party B, because they're both the same moron - me.)

Comment: They deleted everything and then wrote on top in a file hierarchy somewhat similar to the previous state?

Comment: Deleted most things, but the files written later didn't share any names with the deleted files

Comment: How many new files are added by Party B? On the order of 5 or 500?

Comment: Also how many files were deleted? And do you share this feature branch with anyone else? Could you do a rebase and undelete them?

Comment: In general, since they just went on and deleted things, you can't rebase to get files back because rebasing only occurs on commits between the initial state of the branch and the current state, which doesn't include everything. You can run something like: `git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- "$filename")^ -- "$filename"` and see what happens. But you'll have to do that for every file. Otherwise, I think that's too complicated.

Comment: Party A refuses the merge and tosses it back over the wall to Party B with a firm recommendation to do it right. Seriously, that sort of thing should not be the burden of the integrator; the developers are responsible for delivering complete working code to the integrator. Unless the integration flow uses patch sets instead of merge requests... It's probably going to require a commit-by-commit rewrite of new_feature using `git rebase -i` and cancelling all the deletions. Although `git filter-branch` could also be used...

Comment: Problem is that Party A, Party B, and the integrator are all the same idiot - me =P One of my novice mistakes starting out with Git.

Comment: Somewhere on the order of a dozen files added, but hundreds deleted. And again, I still have those files in another branch - I'm not necessarily trying to recover them. I just want a clean way to merge the branches if possible. If it helps, all the files were deleted in one go

Comment: In that case, `git rebase -i` is probably the way to go. Tell it to stop and let you edit the commit where the deletions were done, `git checkout` the files that were deleted, `git add` them, `git commit`, and then `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **safer way** is to **recover the deleted files in new_feature branch and then merge into master** (assume the main branch is master here).

To recover the deleted files in new_feature branch, you need to checkout a temp branch and stash the files from master, then apply the stash work in new_branch branch. Detail steps as below:

```
git checkout new_feature
git checkout -b temp
git rm *.*
git commit -am 'keep empty'
git checkout <latest commit id on master> *.*
git stash
git checkout new_feature
git stash pop
git commit -am 'recovery the deleted files'
git branch -D temp
```